# DocuSign Integration. Is it possible to get auth token without users consent. I want to send docusign envolope email internally using my credentials

Tags: python, django, jwt, docusignapi, docusignconnect

I have an application that sends DocuSign emails to users when clicking on a button from the frontend. So
If I go by Auth code grand or implicit grant, my user has to sign in to their account. For JWT they will be redirected to consent.That means all my users need to have docusign account for sending. Is there any way to send mail from the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the same account to send from, even if "your" users are different. The user on the DocuSign side can be your "system user", a single user/account that you set up using JWT that all envelopes would be coming from. That would mean that the email would always come from the same user. If you want different users acting as the sender of the email - you do need them all to consent. The user that is using the API is the one that the envelope is sent from regardless of choosing Auth Code Grant or JWT Grant.